# Delete keys with pattern in redis having redis-cli password

Tags: redis, redis-cli

How to delete keys with pattern having redis-cli password?

Records i needs to remove:

`redis-cli -p 6379 -a password KEYS "/st_files/281/*" | wc -l`
**9**

I want to remove the values under /st_files/281/*   Which has count 9.

My redis setup has password.

**Redis version is 3.2.3**
I tried:

`redis-cli -p 6379 -a pssword KEYS "/st_files/281/*" | xargs redis-cli DEL`

Result is:

`(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.`

Password i entered is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
redis-cli -a pssword KEYS "/st_files/281/*" | xargs redis-cli -a pssword DEL
```

Comment: I want to delete entries from **1** to **288**. Total it's **350** [  /st_files/**355**/* ]
How can i do in a single command?